# ModalPopupExtender

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I must create ModalPopupExtender. for this, I create one simple application and all my expectation wrok. But when i add my popup in master page it doesn't work, How I can fix this problem?

my popup

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click here to show iframe in modalpopup" />
      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"
         runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel" OkControlID="btnOkay" TargetControlID="Button1"
         PopupControlID="Panel1" Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader">
      </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
      <div id="Panel1" style="display: none;" class="popupConfirmation">
         <iframe id="frameeditexpanse" frameborder="0" src="InnerPage.aspx" height="161">
         </iframe>
         <div class="popup_Buttons" style="display: none">
            <input id="btnOkay" value="Done" type="button" />
            <input id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" type="button" />
         </div>
      </div>
```

my script in InnerPage.aspx

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function okay() {
         window.parent.document.getElementById('btnOkay').click();
      }
      function cancel() {
         window.parent.document.getElementById('btnCancel').click();
      }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place this script on same page with extender

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickOk() {
        $get("<%= btnOkay.ClientID %>").click();
    }

    function clickCancel() {
        $get("<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").click();
    }
</script>
```

and instead of `parent.window.document.getElementById().click()` use `parent.window.clickOk()` and `parent.window.clickCancel()`